# There are more uses of the concept: Transversal, given in Coddington-Levinson book of Theory of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm reading the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem's proof in the book I've mentioned. I feel kind of curious about the concept shown there: the transversal, and how they used it. I would like to know if there are other uses of this concept in other proofs, specially if they are oriented to study properties in ODE's.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but maybe start [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics))

Comment: @polfosol Actually what OP is asking about is closer to [this concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) :) Transversals (or cross-sections) are key instruments in studying such low-dimensional objects as flows without singularities on tori (could be reduced to circle mappings), limit cycles on plane and even for occurence of chaotic behaviour in case of Shilnikov saddle-focus loop. The behaviour of trajectories in the neighbourhood of periodic orbit also could be studied by means of studying properties of fixed point of corresponding Poincar\'e mapping.